# How do I return raw bytes in a HTTP Response in Tower Web?

Tags: rust

I am developing an API using the tower_web framework, and for some API calls, it would be best to just return bytes with a content type like "`application/octet-stream`". This data is not directly read from a file, but generated dynamically, so I can't refer to the example code for serving a static file.
For implementing the desired functionality, I tried using a `http::Response<Vec<u8>>` with a body using a u8 array. Here are the relevant snippets of my code, for testing purposes I used a u8 array filled with zeroes, that would later be the data I want to send to the client:

```
extern crate tower_web;
use tower_web::ServiceBuilder;
use http::Response as HttpResponse;

const SERVER_ADDRESS : &str = "127.0.0.1:8080";

[...]

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct HttpApi;

impl_web! {
    impl HttpApi {

        [...]

        #[get("/test")]
        #[content_type("application/octet-stream")]
        fn test(&self) -> http::Response<Vec<u8>> {
            let response = HttpResponse::builder().status(200).body([0u8;16]);
            println!("{:?}", response);
            response
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let addr = SERVER_ADDRESS.parse().expect("Invalid address");
    println!("Listening on http://{}", addr);

    ServiceBuilder::new()
        .resource(HttpApi)
        .run(&addr)
        .unwrap();
}
```

However, when I try to build it using cargo, I get this error:

```
the trait `tower_web::codegen::futures::Future` is not implemented for `http::Response<Vec<u8>>`
```

I also tried setting the type returned by the function to a *Result* wrapping the `http::Response<Vec<u8>>` and (), as it would work that way when I try returning strings or json. This gave me the error

> the trait `BufStream` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`

Is there any simple way to solve this, or any other approach for returning bytes as the body of a HTTP Response in Tower Web?

Comment: What version of `http` are you using? `tower` uses `http 0.1` internally but you might have `http 0.2`

Comment: I'm using `http` 0.1.7, but I previously tried the latest version as well, it didn't make any difference

Comment: I decided to switch to `actix_web` as it appears to provide all the features I need, so I don't need an answer anymore. But I'm still interested in how it could work with `tower`, because responding with something different than `String` or `Json` should be a rather basic thing in any web framework.